# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Adding Cipher

Tags: ssl, cipher, schannel

this might be a complete newbee question.
I have an 2012 R2 Server on which an application should call a partner who only offers the following ciphers:
(0xc02f) TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS 128
(0xc030) TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) FS

If i check schnannel reg key my system offers:
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_CK_RC4_128_WITH_MD5
SSL_CK_DES_192_EDE3_CBC_WITH_MD5

Can i just add the cipher in the regkey and restart or do i have to make an update of some kind?

Best Regards
Moritz

Comment: Have a look right here: https://www.howtogeek.com/221080/how-to-update-your-windows-server-cipher-suite-for-better-security/(and that's not a newbie question, I've already been looking for that but have never done research haha, that deserve an upvote).

Comment: For more information about supported cipher suites for ws 2012 see here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1

Comment: I'm wondering why Windows doesn't have a cipher factory that just parses the text and initiates each piece, instead of having a steadfast set of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that cipher support is version related and server 2012 r2 is not supporting the wanted ciphers. There seems to be no way to add new ciphers beside updating the OS.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel